# Acyclic Dependency Principle - How could component dependency cycles be reason for "morning-after syndrome"?

Tags: java, c#, architecture, dependencies, design-principles

I am reading "Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#" by Robert Martin.
And currently I am reading about Acyclic Dependency Principle(ADP). And I cant udnerstand one part in that section. Let me explain the part in a short.

Firstly author gives us the definition of  "morning-after syndrome".

> Have you ever worked all day, gotten some stuff working, and then gone
>   home, only to arrive the next morning to find that your stuff no
>   longer works? Why doesn't it work? Because somebody stayed later than
>   you and changed something you depend on! I call this "the
>   morning-after syndrome."

Then he explains how to solve the problem:

> The solution to this problem is to partition the development
>   environment into releasable components. The components become units of
>   work that can be the responsibility of a developer or a team of
>   developers. When developers get a component working, they release it
>   for use by the other developers. They give it a release number, and
>   move it into a directory for other teams to use, and continue to
>   modify their component in their own private areas. Everyone else uses
>   the released version. As new releases of a component are made, other
>   teams can decide whether to immediately adopt the new release. If they
>   decide not to, they simply continue using the old release. Once they
>   decide that they are ready, they begin to use the new release.

Then he shows us an example for component structure which has not any depdendancy cycle:

> What isimportant is the dependency structure of the components. Note
>   that this structure is a directed graph. The components are the nodes,
>   and the dependency relationships are the directed edges.

[image]

And then let us say that a new requirement forces us to change one of the classes in `MyDialogs` such that it makes use of a class in `MyApplication`. As you can guess, it creates dependancy cycle:

[image]

And then he notes that:

> The cycle forces `MyApplication`, `MyTasks`, and `MyDialogs` to always be
>   released at the same time.

**My question is that: Why?** **If we are using releasable components, why other two components must be released at the same time with `MyDialogs`?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The cycle forces ... to *always* be released at the same time" is not actually true.

But the cyclic dependency means that you *can* make simultaneous changes to `MyApplication` and `MyDialogs` that depend on each other, and *then* you will have to release them at the same time.

If you ensure that your component dependencies are acyclic, then you are *never* forced to release both at the same time.

Also, if there is a dependency cycle in the *first* release of the components, then you will have to release them all at the same time initially.